# easy way for USA city/state array

Tags: javascript, arrays

so I have this web app that uses this location select variable in javascript. I am wondering if there is a easy way to convert/do this for USA without have to type in every state and city.

```
  var location_selectors = {"country":["Australia"],"state":{"Australia":["Australian Capital Territory","New South Wales","Northern Territory","Queensland","South Australia","Tasmania","Victoria","Western Australia"]},"city":{"Australian Capital Territory":["Canberra"],"New South Wales":["Sydney","Albury","Armidale","Bathurst","Broken Hill","Cessnock","Coffs Harbour","Dubbo","Gosford","Goulburn","Grafton","Griffith","Lake Macquarie","Lismore","Maitland","Newcastle","Nowra","Orange","Port Macquarie","Queanbeyan","Tamworth","Tweed Heads","Wagga Wagga","Wollongong","Wyong"],"Northern Territory":["Darwin","Alice Springs","Katherine","Palmerston"],"Queensland":["Brisbane","Bundaberg","Cairns","Charters Towers","Gladstone","Gold Coast","Gympie","Hervey Bay","Ipswich","Logan City","Mackay","Maryborough","Mount Isa","Nambour","Redcliffe","Rockhampton","Sunshine Coast","Thuringowa","Toowoomba","Townsville"],"South Australia":["Adelaide","Mount Gambier","Murray Bridge","Port Augusta","Port Pirie","Port Lincoln","Victor Harbor","Whyalla"],"Tasmania":["Hobart","Burnie","Clarence","Devonport","Glenorchy","Launceston"],"Victoria":["Melbourne","Benalla","Ballarat","Bendigo","Geelong","Latrobe City","Mildura","Shepparton","Swan     Hill","Wangaratta","Warrnambool","Wodonga"],"Western Australia":    ["Perth","Albany","Broome","Bunbury","Geraldton","Fremantle","Kalgoorlie","Mandu    rah","Port Hedland"]}};
```

heres the php version

```
$location_selectors = [
'country' => [
    'Australia',
],
'state' => [
    'Australia' => [
        'Australian Capital Territory',
        'New South Wales',
        'Northern Territory',
        'Queensland',
        'South Australia',
        'Tasmania',
        'Victoria',
        'Western Australia',
    ],
],
'city' => [
    'Australian Capital Territory' => [
        'Canberra',
    ],
    'New South Wales' => [
        'Sydney',
        'Albury',
        'Armidale',
        'Bathurst',
        'Broken Hill',
        'Cessnock',
        'Coffs Harbour',
        'Dubbo',
        'Gosford',
        'Goulburn',
        'Grafton',
        'Griffith',
        'Lake Macquarie',
        'Lismore',
        'Maitland',
        'Newcastle',
        'Nowra',
        'Orange',
        'Port Macquarie',
        'Queanbeyan',
        'Tamworth',
        'Tweed Heads',
        'Wagga Wagga',
        'Wollongong',
        'Wyong',
    ],
    'Northern Territory' => [
        'Darwin',
        'Alice Springs',
        'Katherine',
        'Palmerston',
    ],
    'Queensland' => [
        'Brisbane',
        'Bundaberg',
        'Cairns',
        'Charters Towers',
        'Gladstone',
        'Gold Coast',
        'Gympie',
        'Hervey Bay',
        'Ipswich',
        'Logan City',
        'Mackay',
        'Maryborough',
        'Mount Isa',
        'Nambour',
        'Redcliffe',
        'Rockhampton',
        'Sunshine Coast',
        'Thuringowa',
        'Toowoomba',
        'Townsville',
    ],
    'South Australia' => [
        'Adelaide',
        'Mount Gambier',
        'Murray Bridge',
        'Port Augusta',
        'Port Pirie',
        'Port Lincoln',
        'Victor Harbor',
        'Whyalla',
    ],
    'Tasmania' => [
        'Hobart',
        'Burnie',
        'Clarence',
        'Devonport',
        'Glenorchy',
        'Launceston',
    ],
    'Victoria' => [
        'Melbourne',
        'Benalla',
        'Ballarat',
        'Bendigo',
        'Geelong',
        'Latrobe City',
        'Mildura',
        'Shepparton',
        'Swan Hill',
        'Wangaratta',
        'Warrnambool',
        'Wodonga',
    ],
    'Western Australia' => [
        'Perth',
        'Albany',
        'Broome',
        'Bunbury',
        'Geraldton',
        'Fremantle',
        'Kalgoorlie',
        'Mandurah',
        'Port Hedland',
    ],
],
```

];

Comment: Copy/Paste. https://gist.github.com/mshafrir/2646763

Comment: You're probably out of luck for a clean, correctly formatted city/state combination. USA is >10x the population, so you're looking at 10x the cities. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about finding a data resource/recommendation than a programming problem. There appear to be a number of online resources for this data (google for "us cities and states csv"); it will be up to you to find the right one and manipulate it into your required format.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search yielded this:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/master/countriesToCities.json

http://www.geobytes.com/free-ajax-cities-jsonp-api/

First one should be fine for basic use. Dont think it has states though. Might want to use the second API in that case